# I can not name the field "from"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I write a script for myself on python, I use the dataclass library, I have a ready-made DTO written in Java, which I try to repeat on the python, there is a field called "from", what can I call this field in python, because I can't call him the same way?

I use python 3.7 and dataclass_json

```py
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Direction:
    from: Optional[str]
    to: Optional[str]
```

```
from: Optional[str]
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

`from` is a [reserved word](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python. It is used in `raise` statements to assign a parent exception, and in `yield from` to delegate to an iterator.

A common workaround is to append an underscore if you wish to use a reserved word as a variable (e.g., use `from_`). You can see some examples of this in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator) module, which defines functions like [`in_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.in_), [`is_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_), and [`not_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.not_). This frequently applies to built in functions and classes too, even though they aren't technically reserved. Notice that in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), prepending an underscore has slightly special meaning, while appending one does not.

Fun bonus fact: the [`keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) module has a full list of keywords ([`kwlist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist)) and let's you check if a word is a keyword ([`iskeyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.iskeyword)) directly in the interpreter. This applies even for new keywords that come from a `__future__` import.

Comment: Yeah, I know it, how can I get around this? Any tips?

Comment: @Reality. Updated

Comment: This method does not suit me. I can not change the name of the object that comes to me.

Comment: @Reality. Then perhaps Python is not a good choice? Where does `dataclass_json` come from? Perhaps there's a solution there?

Comment: @Reality, it seems you can modify the attribute name based on this [test from the source code](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json/commit/ec8891d8db56ff9be7d0c915b9cd3de2d88bf3e2#diff-dfeef99d255ac5ae6180de368eccdef9L35).  Example: `... class Direction: frm: Optional[str] = field(metadata=config(field_name='from')) ...`

Comment: @RealityIsGay `field(metadata={"data_key": "from"})`